# Criando banco de dados no Visual Studio

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server, visual-studio, ide, tsql

Se eu criar o banco de dados do meu projeto no Visual Studio ele sempre vai usar a linguagem T-SQL para criar a manipular? Ou eu posso criar todo o banco com as relações e tudo mais no SQL Server Management Studio e depois só conectar no Visual Studio?

O motivo da pergunta é porque tive problemas quando criei o banco do SQL Server Management Studio e fui tentar fazer as relações no VS parece que os dois não se comunicam por usarem linguagens SQL diferentes.

Eu não estudei nada sobre T-SQL ainda. mas sei que é diferente do SQL Server que eu estudei, por isso estou confuso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> se eu criar o banco de dados do meu projeto no Visual Studio ele sempre vai usar a linguagem T-SQL para criar a manipular?

Não é tão simples assim. T-SQL é a linguagem padrão para as *stored procedures*. Mas é possível usar outras linguagens, você decide qual usar. E pode até não criar *stored procedures*. Se não está usando isso, apenas *query* usa T-SQL, mas não é fácil usar algo específico dela, na prática só usará comando do SQL padrão.

> Ou eu posso criar todo o banco com as relações e tudo mais no SQL Server Management Studio e depois só conectar no Visual Studio?

Sim, pode fazer isso, um nada tem a ver com o outro e cada um serve para uma coisa diferente. O Visual Studio até tem algumas facilidades para gerenciar o SQL Server, mas não é tão completo quanto o software feito só para gerenciá-lo.

> O motivo da pergunta é pq tive problemas quando criei o banco do SQL Server Management Studio e fui tentar fazer as relações no VS parece que os dois não se comunicam por usarem linguagens SQL diferentes

Não, isso não procede, não existe isso porque na verdade o Visual Studio é só um IDE de programação, assim como o Management Studio é só um IDE do SQL Server. Quando você vai acessar o banco de dados ele é um só não importa de onde está acessando, portanto não existe SQL diferentes. Se teve algum problema é porque fez algo errado em algum caso.

Se consegue fazer em um deles corretamente faça assim então.